# Uncaught TypeError: mydata.filter is not a function

Tags: javascript, массивы

Пытаюсь отфильтровать массив `let mydata`.
Выдает ошибку

> Uncaught TypeError: mydata.filter is not a function.
> Что не так?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event){
        myFunction();
    });

    function myFunction(){
        let filterPar = urlVar[1] ;
        let mydata = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("mydata"));
        let newTable = mydata.filter(function (param){return param[2]=="filterPar";});
    }

</script>
```

Comment: очевидно, что mydata - Это не массив и у него нет метода filter

Comment: mydata  это массив  в консоль выводится{data: Array(46), errors: Array(0), meta: {…}} typeof Object.

Comment: Ну где же массив, когда объект? :-) массивами являются его свойства `data` и `errors`

Comment: Сделай пожалуйста console.log( typeof mydata )
filter это метод работает для Array!

Comment: а filter та неплохо работает и для Object ````[].filter.call({length:3,'0':2,'1':1,'2':0},v=>v) //[2,1]```` :D

Answer (score -1):

```
function myFunction(){
   let filterPar = urlVar[1] ;
   let mydata = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("mydata"));
   //mydata все-же объект {data: Array(46), errors: Array(0), meta: {…}}
   if( Array.isArray(mydata)){ 
   //Array.isArray вернет true если аргумент будет массивом
        console.log('mydata is array');
        var newTable = mydata.filter(function (param){return param[2]=="filterPar";});
   } else {
        console.log('mydata is object');
        var newTable = mydata
        .data //собственно тут массив, он внутри объекта mydata
        .filter(function (param){return param[2]=="filterPar";});
   }
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",myFunction);
//для краткости в addEventListener можно передать сразу myFunction
```

Comment: Спасибо. Сама додумалась что нужно добавить data
 let newTable = mydata.data.filter(function (param) { return param[2]== filterPar});
Все заработало.